# How do I implement a DependencyProperty on a custom wpf control for an ImageSource?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, imagesource

How do I implement a `DependencyProperty` on a custom wpf control for an `ImageSource`?

I created a custom control (button) which amongst other things does display an image. I want to be able to set the ImageSource for the image from the outside of the control, so I implemented a DependencyProperty. Whenever I try to change the ImageSource though, I am getting a `SystemInvalidOperationException`: *"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."*

OK, so the main thread cannot access the image control, so I need to use the Dispatcher - but where and how? Apparently the exception is thrown in the setter, executing `SetValue(ImageProperty, value);`

tv_CallStart.xaml:

```xml
<Button x:Class="EHS_TAPI_Client.Controls.tv_CallStart" x:Name="CallButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="24" d:DesignWidth="24" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0"
         Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#FF2467FF" UseLayoutRounding="True">

         <Image x:Name="myImage"
                Source="{Binding ElementName=CallButton, Path=CallImage}" />
</Button>
```

tv_CallStart.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace EHS_TAPI_Client.Controls
{
    public partial class InitiateCallButton : Button
    {
        public ImageSource CallImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(CallImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CallImageProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CallImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CallImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(InitiateCallButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public InitiateCallButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

setting the image from the code-behind of the UI-thread:

```cs
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/EHS-TAPI-Client;component/Images/call-start.png");
bi.EndInit();
bi.Freeze();
CallButton.CallImage = bi;
```

and the MainWindow.xaml where the control is initialised:

```xml
<ctl:InitiateCallButton x:Name="CallButton" CallImage="/Images/call-start.png" />
```

Adapted the above source code to reflect my progress..

**Solution:**

The code posted above is working fine. The important change from the initial version is the addition of the Freeze() method from the UI thread (see accepted answer). The actual problem in *my* project is not the button *not* being initialised in the UI thread, *but* the new image being set from another thread. The image is set in an event handler which itself is triggered from another thread. I resolved the problem by using the `Dispatcher`:

```cs
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/EHS-TAPI-Client;component/Images/call-start.png");
bi.EndInit();
bi.Freeze();
if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
        {
            CallButton.CallImage = bi;
        });
}
else
{
    CallButton.CallImage = bi;
}
```

Comment: You are right and I'm ashamed. Especially as I tend to follow best practices and naming conventions usually. Those classes were created some time ago and I can't even remember why I did not name them properly this time. Which actually makes things even worse o.O

Comment: At least you appear to not have mixed german into it, which might be even worse:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you use an image internally it makes sense to reuse the `Image.SourceProperty` and not that of `ImageBrush`.
2. Make sure to create all thread-affine elements on the UI-thread or you need to [`Freeze`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) them if they are [freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) before you do anything cross-thread with them. ([`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) is a `Freezable`)
3. The property changed handler is not hooked up so it will never be called, its content is pointless anyway though, the property has already been set when the handler is called.

Comment: 1. ImageBrush is used so the existing DependencyProperty can be used instead of creating a new one, as by using ImageBrush one can use its ImageSourceProperty.AddOwner() Method. Anyway, for now I reverted back to my old code which does implement a *new* DependencyProperty of type ImageSource, just as you suggested. 2) I still seem to have trouble getting that point. AFAIK Freeze makes the object not modifyable. But I want to change the image - I probably read the example code I have found so far from the wrong perspective, hence I don't really get how and why to implement it ...

Comment: I did not suggest implement the from scratch, i just said you took the wrong pick to call `AddOwner` on. If you need to modify the image after creating it you need to create it on the UI-thread. But why would you need to do that? If you need a new image just create one, freeze it and pass it to the property, freezables are usually quite lightweight so that it does not really matter that much that you need to create a new instance.

Comment: 3) True. Anyway, even with the hints you gave I lack the ability to implement it the way I intended. I think I will have to initialise all needed images in the control itself and expose another property instead which determines which image to actually show. This is fine for this control (just not for other uses I can think of, which bothers me). Gonna have to see if Reflector will bring up some additional intel to work with.

Comment: So what does not work about freezing the ImageSource?  It's not like you freeze the property or anything.

Comment: I changed the initial post to reflect the changes I've made. Create the Image in the UI thread, freeze it and set the ImageSource of the control. Apparently I did it wrong though as I still do get the exception.

Comment: That is a problem, because on the UI-thread there should not be an exception even if unfrozen, that means that my guess to what the source of the problem might be was wrong. (Or did you create the custom button on another thread? UI-elements should *always* be created on the UI-thread)

Comment: No the button is created on the UI thread. I guess it really is Reflector-Time, and that will take a while. Nevertheless, your answers have been really helpful, thank you. To see weather I can accept your answer I have to see what that Reflector session yields though.

Comment: Unfortunately only the exception message is not enough to go by here, a call stack, knowing which objects are owned by which thread and which thread is executing the offending code would be helpful.

Comment: Accepted your answer (Freeze needed to be implemented and one of the involved objects was not initialised in the UI thread, tho it was not the control). Also +1 because you hit the nail on the head and because you took your time to help find the solution. Thanks!