# Bind Dependency property to Image source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

C of a ToggleButton which switch the image of the button with triggers. Now I want to create DP for the images paths and to bind it to the source of the Image(through BitmapImage,UriSource) so when I use the U.C I can set the paths of the two Images in the xaml file.

the following code run but crushes before the window rises up,an exception is thrown - 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.'
And the inner exception - "An System.InvalidOperationException is thrown when a method of an object is called when the state of the object cannot support the method call. The exception is also thrown when a method attempts to manipulate the UI from a thread that is not the main or UI thread."
Someone knows why it cruses and how to fix it??

U.C xaml file:

```
UserControl x:Class="ButtonChangeImage.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnCI">
            <ToggleButton.Content >
                <Image Name="img" Source="C:\Users\AmitL\Desktop\joecocker.jpg"/>
            </ToggleButton.Content>
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference img}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ElementName=FirstImage}"/>
                                            <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="C:\Users\AmitL\Desktop\james-brown-010.jpg"/>--><!--if I switch to this line it works fine!-->
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>

            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

U.C cs file:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstImageDP = DependencyProperty.Register("FirstImage", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(@"C:\Users\AmitL\Desktop\james-brown-010.jpg", new PropertyChangedCallback(FirstImageSource)));
        private string m_strFirstImage = string.Empty;

        private static void FirstImageSource(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            UserControl1 l_UCBtnSwitchImage = (UserControl1)obj;
            l_UCBtnSwitchImage.m_strFirstImage = (string)args.NewValue;
        }

        public string FirstImage
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(FirstImageDP);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(FirstImageDP, value);
            }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler Click
        {
            add { btnCI.Click += value; }
            remove { btnCI.Click -= value; }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

xaml window:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonChangeImage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:ButtonChangeImage"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <m:UserControl1 Click="ToggleButton_Checked" FirstImage="C:\Users\AmitL\Desktop\james-brown-010.jpg"></m:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If `FirstImage` is a property, then why not just use `<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding FirstImage}" />`?

Comment: @Sheridan tried that.. same results..

Comment: a) What is the value of `FirstImage` at run time? and b) What error(s) are you getting in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Sheridan
I've documented the exceptions in the question..

Comment: @Sheridan
I've documented the exceptions in the question..
I can't debug It and see FirstImage value in real time (I've set a breake point on the InitializeComponent line but it doesn't help) anyway I've set it to "C:\Users\AmitL\Desktop\james-brown-010.jpg"
Here is my mail amitlipman11@gmail.com if you want to contact, I can even send you the v.s solution.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: *I can't debug It and see FirstImage value in real time*... why not? Just add a break point to `FirstImageSource`. Also, I didn't ask you to specify your `Exception`... I quite clearly asked you *What error(s) are you getting in the Output Window in Visual Studio?*

Comment: @Sheridan, I meant that the exception is thrown before it reach a point I can see it's value. I've tried to put a break point there but it doesn't reach that line. these are the errors, sorry I missed it before:

Comment: The thread 0x2b9c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x830 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xd20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2ef0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'ButtonChangeImage.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ButtonChangeImage.vshost.exe): Loaded 'E:\Branch 9 - LAB TButton trigger images and click CBFunc\ButtonChangeImage\ButtonChangeImage\bin\Debug\ButtonChangeImage.exe'. Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ButtonChangeImage.App..ctor'

Comment: Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ButtonChangeImage.App..ctor'
'ButtonChangeImage.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ButtonChangeImage.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ButtonChangeImage.App.Main'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ButtonChangeImage.App.InitializeComponent'

Comment: Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ButtonChangeImage.App.InitializeComponent'
The program '[8252] ButtonChangeImage.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8252] ButtonChangeImage.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Those don't look like binding errors from the *Output Window in Visual Studio*... they start with the word *Error*.

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399210/how-do-i-implement-a-dependencyproperty-on-a-custom-wpf-control-for-an-imagesour

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the `UriSource` of your `BitmapImage` at runtime. [You can't do it like this, by simply changing the filepath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource(v=vs.110).aspx). `BitmapImage` implements the interface [ISupportInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.aspx) and requires initialization.

That means, you will have to [create the new BitmapImage with the new source every time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473(v=vs.90).aspx), or initialize it (by calling [BeginInit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit(v=vs.110).aspx) and [EndInit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.endinit(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Changing the `Uri` is not enough, you have to change the whole `BitmapImage`.

I once made a [MarkupExtension combined with a Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548744/891715) to deal with such a situation. It takes a path, or a binding, and may require some modification to work in your case.